# source bash file doesnt work, still asks for variables or doesnt work

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu-18.04

I am having a problem using source ./admin-openrc.sh file to get variables for kn apply ( a cloud cluster creator application).

but it doesnt seem te work.

[image]

When I then try to use the source command in the same line it just doesnt run anything and gives me a black line.

[image]

Contents of the shell file:

```
    export OS_AUTH_URL=http://192.168.1.200/identity
# With the addition of Keystone we have standardized on the term **project** as the entity that owns the resources.
export OS_PROJECT_ID=995dadc5b03d4b02a1cf5a94b430f3fd
export OS_PROJECT_NAME="admin"
export OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME="Default"
if [ -z "$OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME" ]; then unset OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME; fi
export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID="default"
if [ -z "$OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID" ]; then unset OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID; fi
# unset v2.0 items in case set
unset OS_TENANT_ID unset OS_TENANT_NAME
# In addition to the owning entity (tenant), OpenStack stores the entity performing the action as the **user**.
export OS_USERNAME="admin"
# With Keystone you pass the keystone password.
# echo "Please enter your OpenStack Password for project $OS_PROJECT_NAME as user $OS_USERNAME: " read -sr OS_PASSWORD_INPUT
export OS_PASSWORD=Admin00
# If your configuration has multiple regions, we set that information here. OS_REGION_NAME is optional and only valid in
# certain environments.
export OS_REGION_NAME="RegionOne"
# Don't leave a blank variable, unset it if it was empty
if [ -z "$OS_REGION_NAME" ]; then unset OS_REGION_NAME; fi
export OS_INTERFACE=public
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
```

I have tried chmod the permissions to 777 because the shell file might not be executable or something but to no avail.

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `kn apply` is being run under sudo (With a fresh environment as Root). However you are applying the source on your standard user environment.

There is a few ways you can solve this

a) After sourcing the script, preserve the environment using `sudo -E kn apply` but this depends on your sudo configuration / security policy.

b) Run the source within the Sudo'ed environment (i personally prefer this approach)

`sudo -- bash -c "source /home/administrator/devstack/admin-openrc.sh ; kn apply"`

Comment: I am going to try this. I'll let you know. Thanks for replying :)

Comment: This worked. Was struggling for a few hours yesterday. THANKS A LOT.